# Another issue with Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer

Tags: c#, sql, smo, transfer

I don't understand why sometimes Transfer.ScriptTransfer() generates a script where some CREATE VIEW statements come even before the actual table declarations.

How's that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Possible b/c both the view and the table exist at the time of scripting.
- Why would a script be created that couldn't possibly successfully run?  I don't know.  Bug?

Comment: I don't know why either. 
Generator generates the script and puts all the stuff in a messy order. Sometimes CREATE VIEW statements come first and when you run the script it doesn't work because those tables, that the VIEW refers to, haven't been yet created, so you have to move entire CREATE VIEW block after all table declarations. 
Manually.